# How can I implement this custom picker control in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, custom-controls

I was browsing through the Behance iOS app and saw this nifty custom picker that filters the content. I immediately starting thinking how it can be done in SwiftUI.

The closest thing I have tried out was from this article https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-2/

Using anchor preferences, we can animate the transition of the border between selections. However, I am stumped as to how we can also animate the current selection into the center of the frame.

Please view the gif below for reference of what I’m trying to replicate.

[image]